# Error: Invalid override in ==

Tags: dart, overriding, subtype

The following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid override. The type of Bar.== ((Bar) → bool) is not a subtype of 
Foo.== ((Foo) → bool).
```

Occurs in line 10 of the following code (v1.15.0):

```
1  class Foo {
2    int foo;

3    Foo(this.foo);

4    bool operator ==(Foo a) => foo == a.foo;
5    int get hashCode => foo * 17;
6  }

7  class Bar extends Foo {
8    int bar;

8    Bar(int foo, this.bar) : super(foo);

10   bool operator ==(Bar a) => (bar == a.bar) && (foo == a.foo);
11   int get hashCode => bar * (foo * 17);
12 }
```

I have assumed that Bar is a subtype of Foo.  What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Unrelated to the error, the `operator==` method should accept any `Object`. If you have the code above and have a `Bar` and a `Foo` in the same `HashSet`, then you get type errors when it tries to do `bar == foo` because `Bar.operator==` doesn't accept a `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a bug.  I just realized that the == operator should probably have a type of Object to work effectively.  A better error message would be helpful.

Comment: As you've already figured out, when you override the == operator, the parameter should be of type Object, and you should also override the hashCode getter. Just wanted to add a good source - http://work.j832.com/2014/05/equality-and-dart.html

Comment: Thanks.  Good article!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you mentioned Class name in operator ==

```
1  class Foo {
2    int foo;

3    Foo(this.foo);

4    bool operator ==(Foo a) => foo == a.foo;
5    int get hashCode => foo * 17;
6  }

7  class Bar extends Foo {
8    int bar;

8    Bar(int foo, this.bar) : super(foo);

10   bool operator ==(Bar a) => (bar == a.bar) && (foo == a.foo);
11   int get hashCode => bar * (foo * 17);
12 }
```

bool operator ==(Foo a) => foo == a.foo;

bool operator ==(Bar a) => (bar == a.bar) && (foo == a.foo);

These two lines cause problems.

You must update these lines like this.

bool operator ==(a) => foo == a.foo;

bool operator ==(a) => (bar == a.bar) && (foo == a.foo);